# Difference between INSERT INTO and INSERT ALL INTO

Tags: sql, oracle

While I was inserting some records in table i found that..

```
INSERT INTO T_CANDYBAR_DATA   
  SELECT CONSUMER_ID,CANDYBAR_NAME,SURVEY_YEAR,GENDER,1 AS STAT_TYPE,OVERALL_RATING 
  FROM CANDYBAR_CONSUMPTION_DATA
  UNION
  SELECT CONSUMER_ID,CANDYBAR_NAME,SURVEY_YEAR,GENDER,2 AS STAT_TYPE,NUMBER_BARS_CONSUMED 
  FROM CANDYBAR_CONSUMPTION_DATA;
```

`79 rows inserted.`

```
INSERT ALL
INTO t_candybar_data VALUES (consumer_id,candybar_name,survey_year,gender,1,overall_rating)
INTO t_candybar_data VALUES (consumer_id,candybar_name,survey_year,gender,2,number_bars_consumed)
SELECT  * FROM candybar_consumption_data
```

`86 rows inserted.`

I have read somewhere that `INSERT ALL INTO` automatically unions then why those difference is showing.

Comment: UNION eliminates duplicate records from the resultset, while INSERT ALL doesn't. There were 7 duplicate records and the first query removed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your queries are different—your first is with `UNION` and your second is without—so they are naturally inserting different numbers of values. As far as what `INSERT ALL` is versus a straight `INSERT`:

- `INSERT` can be used for inserting new records to a **single** table.
- `INSERT ALL` can be used for inserting new records to **multiple** tables based on the query condition.

So your assumption as stated here:

> I have read somewhere that `INSERT ALL INTO` automatically unions then
>   why those difference is showing.

Is incorrect. `INSERT ALL` doesn’t have anything to do with `UNION` in any way. But that said, you might be mixing up [`UNION ALL` as explained here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union_all.php).

> The SQL UNION ALL operator is used to combine the result sets of 2 or
>   more SELECT statements. It returns all rows from the query (even if
>   the row exists in more than one of the SELECT statements).
>
> Each SELECT statement within the UNION ALL must have the same number
>   of fields in the result sets with similar data types.